# Cannot Bundle Install due to an error compiling Unf_ext '

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi, debian

I'm trying to install Huginn on a raspberry pi 3 running Debian Jesse (arm).  Bundle install fails while trying to install unf_ext:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /tmp/bundler20161007-16062-unp7l7unf_ext-0.0.7.1/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.1/ext/unf_ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20161007-16062-wdgukt.rb extconf.rb
```

When I try: sudo gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.1'  I get the following error:

```
current directory: /tmp/bundler20161007-16062-unp7l7unf_ext-0.0.7.1/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.1/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling unf.cc
In file included from unf/normalizer.hh:10:0,
             from unf.cc:1:

unf/table.hh:13539:25: error: narrowing conversion of ‘-27’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
  -77, -39,-124, -39,-123};
```

The above is followed by a very long list of err: narrowing conversion of ## from int to char inside {} [-Wnarrowing] errors

I am compiling with: 6.1.1 20160802 (Raspbian 6.1.1-11+rpi1)

I tried gem update, but that didn't help.  Nor did adding flags in ext/unf_ext/extconf.rb

```
+$CXXFLAGS += " -fsigned-char "
+
```

I'm a beginner with all of this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: I've [published my gem on Github](https://github.com/appleorange1/unf_ext-0.0.6-arm) to save people the effort of making their own. If you want to use mine, then just run these two commands:

```
wget https://github.com/appleorange1/unf_ext-0.0.6-arm/raw/master/unf_ext-0.0.6.gem
gem install ./unf_ext-0.0.6.gem
```

If you want to find out how I did this, keep reading:

I've was having this problem too (on a Chromebook C201PA). The issue is that your changes to ext/unf_ext/extconf.rb keep getting overwritten when you run "gem install". I'm not sure why this is, but I got around this problem by creating a local gem.

To do this, download the upstream gem version you want from [this page](https://rubygems.org/gems/unf_ext/versions). I used version 0.0.6.

Then, unpack the upstream gem:

```
gem unpack unf_ext-0.0.6.gem
```

After you've extracted the upstream gem, rename it so that you don't confuse it with your local gem. (You don't have to do this; it's just a suggestion.)

```
mv unf_ext-0.0.6.gem unf_ext-0.0.6-upstream.gem
```

Now, move into the unpacked gem.

```
cd unf_ext-0.0.6
```

Then, add the line `$CXXFLAGS += ' -fsigned-char'` to the file `ext/unf_ext/extconf.rb`. (I put it on the third line, just under `have_library('stdc++')`.)

```
vi ext/unf_ext/extconf.rb
```

Then, you can build and install the gem:

```
gem build unf_ext.gemspec
gem install ./unf_ext-0.0.6.gem
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with a later version bundled within a Rails project's Gemfile.lock:

```
bundle install
```

which called:

```
gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.2'
```

I was able to modify the Gemfile.lock and change the unf_ext version to `0.0.7.4`; the unf_ext library has been updated in April 2017 to include ARM processor support. Read the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/knu/ruby-unf_ext/issues/26).

This is not as comprehensive as obscurityenthusiast's answer and could potentially break your solution. Do not change locked version strings without careful consideration.